# Unable to properly remove a D3 element

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I'm trying to remove a bar chart using the remove method and insert a new one.   When I execute remove() on the selection, the SVG contents gets blanked out, but the svg element is still there in the DOM and takes up space on the screen.  The new version of the SVG gets added to the right of the empty one.  When I instead execute remove() on the containing div, then the svg goes away completely, but when I call my code to insert the new version, the new chart is not getting created.

```
D3_BarChart.update = (el, data, configuration, chart) => {
  // d3.select(el).remove();
  chart.remove();

  D3_BarChart.create(el, dataSubset, configuration);
};
```

I am executing the D3 code from within React following the "Lifecycle Methods Wrapping" descrbibed in https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/02/react-d3-ecosystem/, so the two libraries should be pretty separated out and not running into each other.

D3 code

```
// d3 is not a top level export
import * as d3 from 'd3';

// Simple Bar Chart from D3 v4 example at https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/bdf28027e0ce70bd132edc64f1dd7ea4
const D3_BarChart = {};

/* eslint-disable prefer-arrow-callback */
/* eslint-disable fun-names */

const dataSubset = `salesperson,sales
Bob,33
Robin,12`;

D3_BarChart.create = (el, data, configuration) => {
  // D3 Code to create the chart

  // Styling
  el.style.fill = 'steelblue';

  data = `salesperson,sales
  Bob,33
  Robin,12
  Anne,41
  Mark,16
  Joe,59
  Eve,38
  Karen,21
  Kirsty,25
  Chris,30
  Lisa,47
  Tom,5
  Stacy,20
  Charles,13
  Mary,29`;

  // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
  const margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  };

  const width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right;

  const height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  // set the ranges
  const x = d3
    .scaleBand()
    .range([0, width])
    .padding(0.1);
  const y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

  // append the svg object to the body of the page
  // append a 'group' element to 'svg'
  // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
  const svg = d3
    .select(el)
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

  // get the data
  const parsedData = d3.csvParse(data);

  // format the data
  parsedData.forEach(function (d) {
    d.sales = +d.sales;
  });

  // Scale the range of the data in the domains
  x.domain(
    parsedData.map(function (d) {
      return d.salesperson;
    })
  );
  y.domain([
    0,
    d3.max(parsedData, function (d) {
      return d.sales;
    })
  ]);

  // append the rectangles for the bar chart
  svg
    .selectAll('.bar')
    .data(parsedData)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'bar')
    .attr('x', function (d) {
      return x(d.salesperson);
    })
    .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
    .attr('y', function (d) {
      return y(d.sales);
    })
    .attr('height', function (d) {
      return height - y(d.sales);
    });

  // add the x Axis
  svg
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(0,${height})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // add the y Axis
  svg.append('g').call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  return svg;
};

D3_BarChart.update = (el, data, configuration, chart) => {
  // D3 Code to update the chart
  console.log('update el', el);
  console.log('update chart', chart);
  d3.select(el).remove();
  // chart.remove();
  D3_BarChart.create(el, dataSubset, configuration);
};

D3_BarChart.destroy = () => {
  // Cleaning code here
};

export default D3_BarChart;
```

React container

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Explore from '../components/Explore';
import D3_BarChart from '../components/d3/D3_BarChart';
import { resetErrorMessage } from '../actions';

class App extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    // Injected by React Redux
    errorMessage: PropTypes.string,
    resetErrorMessage: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    inputValue: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    // Injected by React Router
    children: PropTypes.node
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.setBarChartContainerRef = this.setBarChartContainerRef.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // D3 Code to create the chart
    this.d3_barChart = D3_BarChart.create(
      this.d3_barChartContainerRef,
      this.props.data,
      this.props.config
    );

    setTimeout(() => {
      D3_BarChart.update(this.d3_barChartContainerRef, this.props.data, this.props.config, this.d3_barChart);
    }, 200);
  }

  handleDismissClick = e => {
    this.props.resetErrorMessage();
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  handleChange = nextValue => {
    this.props.history.push(`/${nextValue}`);
  };

  renderErrorMessage() {
    const { errorMessage } = this.props;
    if (!errorMessage) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <p style={{ backgroundColor: '#e99', padding: 10 }}>
        <b>{errorMessage}</b> <button onClick={this.handleDismissClick}>Dismiss</button>
      </p>
    );
  }

  setBarChartContainerRef(element) {
    this.d3_barChartContainerRef = element;
  }

  render() {
    const { children, inputValue } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="d3-container" ref={this.setBarChartContainerRef.bind(this)}>
        {/*  <D3_BarChart value={inputValue} onChange={this.handleChange} /> */}
        {/*         <Explore value={inputValue} onChange={this.handleChange} />*/}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    errorMessage: state.errorMessage,

    inputValue: ownProps.location.pathname.substring(1)
  };
};

export default withRouter(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    {
      resetErrorMessage
    }
  )(App)
);
```

Comment: your `el` is the div, use `d3.select(el).select('svg').remove()`

Comment: It works now.  I should have returned d3.select(el).select('svg') from the create method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The create method needed to return `d3.select(el).select('svg')`, then `chart.remove()` worked.